# Do I need to make a Policy for each permission (Claim)?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1, claims

I have a bunch of user claims stored in "AspNetUserClaims" that look like this

```
view.employee
update.employee
delete.employee
add.employee
```

now I have in my asp.net core api 2.1 some end points like

```
[HttpPost("CreateNewEmployee")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateNewEmployee([FromBody] NewEmployeeDto dto)
{

}
```

Now I want to added a check to make sure they have the claim "add.employee" but I am not sure how.

Can I just add it to the `[Authorize]` tag or do I got to basically make a policy for each of these permissions?

Comment: Claims are not permissions [Identity vs Permissions](https://leastprivilege.com/2016/12/16/identity-vs-permissions/), don't abuse it as such tough they can sometimes play a similar role (like scope claims which tell for which scope/services the token is meant for)

Comment: Yea I read that but it did not make sense to me as first I am not using IdentityServer(though I guess maybe the concept is the same in IdentityCore). Second I did not know what it was meant by "Add the authorization information to your context once you get closer to the resource that actually needs the information." Can you give an example?

Comment: A rough idea is provided by [Policy Server](https://policyserver.io) (from the creators of Identity Server). Its pretty rough configurable via appsettings.json (okay for smaller, not so good for bigger projects). The API surface is same with their commercial offering. You can of course use the abstract classes and do your own implementation

Comment: hmm, I am having a hard time to believe that Microsoft built in Idenitty Stuff has nothing to handle this but so far I can only find Policies but no example on "permissions". I keep looking as I really want something built in or very simple otherwise might just go back to do it with roles as right now my requirements are you get all of them or non pretty much, the permission is on group not on individual.

Comment: Well, a lot of people mix authentication with authorization. ASP.NET Core Identity and Identity Server already imply its about **identifiying** the user, not about his access permissions (ACL, access control list). The official examples also use it for access, but its not as clean in big applications. And when you use JWT, you also have a limit on how much the token can be (cookie, header limitations, bigger jwt increase response time since it needs to be sent on each request). If you are creating a small application you may get away with it, big one, not so much

Comment: As for built-in stuff, Microsoft devs have time constraints, ASP.NET COre identity also do not have the ability to issue tokens yet (though iirc there are plans to add that in future). ASP.NET Identity 2 (for old ASP.NET MVC) had that ability. For advanced problems you need advanced solutions ;)

Comment: Yea this is all very confusing, Like in a situation you going to need 2 different like policy checkers? Like the standard example is making a Policy in Asp.net Identity that checks if a user is over 18 years over. Now What happens say you then need to be 18 years and over and have edit permission. What you need now 2 separate checks instead of just one check?

Comment: Even the old way doing it in roles seems more confusing now as they now have the roleClaims table what seems so pointless to me since 1 claim can be hooked up to 1 role so why bother checking claim and not just look at role name since a claim can't be shared.

Comment: `[Authorize(Policy = "Over18Age", Authorize(Policy = "ManageUsers")]`, you can use more than one Authorize attribute in case you didn't knew. The role claims table adds claims based on the role, i.e. when you have the role "manager", you can add claims to it which are related to view/edit/manage users and orders etc. and in your actions just check the claims (or via policy). This ways claims are more dynamic than rules (you cant add new roles when you add it as claim, since it requires code change to add the rule to the Authorize attribute

Comment: I guess ManageUsers Policy is made up of role claims and not userClaims? I understand benefit of policies as I could have 2 roles and if I needed to add a 3rd role I could just add it to the policy instead of going to each authorize tag and adding the 3rd role. The roleclaims don't make sense to me as say Admin and Contributor role. Each has a role claim of "edit.employee" in the database these would be considered 2 separate role claims. Would the policy understand they are both the same claim?

Comment: Also even if I do make roleclaims wont' I still have to put it in my JWT token otherwise the policy won't know about these claims?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185171/discussion-between-tseng-and-chobo2).